# How to observe data in viewmodel LiveData + Courotine + MVVM + Retrofit

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

The problem is I could not get the response using LiveData and Courotine in the viewModel. Possibly I do not know the right way to do that. The call is

```
interface AuthApiService {
    @POST("v2/5e3cba6a2d00008709d958d0")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun login(
        @Field("username") username: String,
        @Field("password") password: String
    ): Response<AuthToken>
}
```

The repository is

```
class AuthRepository
@Inject
constructor(
    val authApiService: AuthApiService
) {
    suspend fun login(username: String, password: String) = liveData {
        emit(GenericResult.Loading(null))
        try {
            emit(GenericResult.Success(authApiService.login(username, password)))
        } catch (ioException: Exception) {
            emit(GenericResult.Error(ioException))
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do in viewmodel is,

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = authRepository.login(username, password)

            when (result.value) {
                is GenericResult.Loading -> isLoading.postValue(true)
                is GenericResult.Success -> authToken.postValue((result.value as GenericResult.Success<Response<AuthToken>>).data.body())
                is GenericResult.Error -> onMessageError.postValue((result.value as GenericResult.Error).exception)
            }
        }
```

And its not working. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: There is no error. I am not getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the reason why you are not getting the result is because there are no `Observers` for the `LiveData` returned by `authRepository.login(username, password)`

You need to do something like:

```
val result = authRepository.login(username, password)
result.observe(someLifeCycleOwner, Observer {...})
```

This usually happens inside a `Fragment` or `Activity` which are `LifeCyclerOwners`.

Also, `liveData {...}` takes a `suspend` block, but it is not itself a `suspend` function. This means that `login()` does not need to be a `suspend` function.

Comment: Thats the problem. the login function in ViewModel has two arguments. how can I make result variable available in Fragment or Activity.

Comment: Make `result` an instance variable and assign `authRepository.login(username, password)` to it. Then call `.observe()` on it from the `Fragment`.

Comment: In that case, how do I pass the username and password to invoke the call.

Comment: could you please guide me how can I invoke the call, if I keep result = authRepository.login(username, password) in viewmodel.

Comment: You can make `result` a method in the view model that takes in username and password.

Comment: If its a method then how do I observe that method from view?

Comment: By calling `.observe()` on the method? From the `Fragment` it would be `viewModel.login(username, password).observe(...)`

Comment: @Emmanuel i need your help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352752/user-login-using-viewmodel-and-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for architecture using MVVM + Koin
[ https://github.com/parthpatibandha/MvvmCleanKotlin ]

Retrofit interface

```
interface MovieApiService {
    @POST(ApiConstant.API_MOVIES)
    fun getAllMovieList(
        @Query("page") page : String
    ): Deferred<FlickerImageListRS>
}
```

Repository

```
class HomeRepository constructor(
    private val homeLocalDataSource: HomeLocalDataSource,
    private val homeRemoteDataSource: HomeRemoteDataSource
) : BaseRepository(), HomeRepo {
    override suspend fun getAllMovieList(flickerImageListPRQ: FlickerImageListPRQ): Either<MyAppException, FlickerImageListRS> {
        return either(homeRemoteDataSource.getAllMovieList(flickerImageListPRQ))
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MovieListingViewModel constructor(private val homeRepo: HomeRepo) : BaseViewModel() {

    val movieListRSLiveData: MutableLiveData<FlickerImageListRS> = MutableLiveData()
    fun getMovieList(page : String) {
        launch {
            postValue(homeRepo.getAllMovieList(FlickerImageListPRQ(page)), movieListRSLiveData)
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you for understand MVVM with Koin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do I need to use Deferred. None of the new google samples uses that anymore.

Comment: Yes, with latest version of retrofit, you can return FlickerImageListRS directly.